# how to request array of objects using request.POST[] in django

Tags: django

```
   for c in request.POST['colors']:
       col=Colors()
       col.color=c['name']
       col.main_id_id=article.id
       col.save()    
   if request.POST['is_dimension']:
       for wbd in (request.POST['dimension']:
           dim=Dimensions()
           dim.width=wbd['width']
           dim.breadth=wbd['breadth']
           dim.depth=wbd['depth']
           dim.main_id_id=article.id
           dim.save()
```

In above code, if i use request.POST.getlist('colors') instead of this request.POST['colors'] i will get empty array , REQUEST TYPE IS MULTIPART FORM DATA

Comment: It is `request.POST.get_list('is_dimension')`.

Comment: But can you please first *fix* the indentation, and specify with what parameters you call the view? (what are `request.GET` and `request.POST` here?

Comment: request.POST.get_list('is_dimension') ,it is just for validating the checkbox,i just need to get values from the array

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: This will depend on the other end of the request. Are you actually sending an array there? If the POST originates from an html form, show that form.

Comment: i am sending http request from angular.js ,

Comment: Upload.upload({
            url: '/student/create',
            data: $scope.details
        }).then(function (resp) {